# The Rare third passive use

Tags: passive-voice

One of the professors of English named Rama murthy announced 10 years ago that he had invented a rare third passive use.

He gave the following sentence for his analysis.

He gave her books

The passive forms are given below

1. She was given books by him.
2. Her books were given by him
3. Books were given to her by him

   This works if the Indirect object is her  and the direct object is a plural noun such as books

Do you accept that it is an invention ?
 I have asked this question not because I believe that what the professor has claimed is correct but because I want to know how far he is right or wrong
I saw it in all leading English news papers in India.

Comment: Sentence 2 is not equivalent to your active-voice sentence. Are you sure you meant that?

Comment: Also, which one is the invention? They all seem like they've always existed without the need for being invented anew.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes her books is the direct object according to the professor

Comment: What does it mean to have "invented" a piece of language? If nobody has used it before it's an innovation, and may or may not become accepted. If people are commonly using it then it's not an invention.

Comment: @DJClayworth refer to a dictionary we can invent a story for laugh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sentence 2 is not equivalent to the active-voice sentence.

In the active-voice sentence and in sentences 1 and 3, “*her*” is the female third-person singular objective-case personal pronoun. In sentence 2, “*her*” is the female third-person singular possessive pronoun. In sentence 2, “*her books*” is a single object, the direct object.

That becomes clearer when you switch the sexes of the persons involved.

- She gave him books.
- He was given books by her.
- His books were given by her (to him or to another person). Note that **Him books were given by her* doesn’t work.
- Books were given to him by her.

There’s nothing rare about the passive-voice use in any of the passive-voice sentences.

**Addendum** The obfuscation works better for plural nouns as direct object, because of the article that only appears in the singular direct object singular without a possessive pronoun.

- He gave her a book.
- She was given a book by him.
- Her book was given by him (to her or to another person). Note that **Her a book was given by him* doesn’t work.
- A book was given to her by him.

Comment: You could say "To her, books were given by him."

Comment: It's equivalent to one reading of the active-voice sentence.

Comment: @Minty: The reading of the active-voice sentence equivalent to sentence 2 feels incomplete to me. Either an indirect object is missing, or the word “away”. But I confess the reading “He gave the books that belong to her” hadn’t occured to me before you brought it up.

Comment: +1 as this answer correctly shows that the argument the OP attributes to Prof. Ramamurthy is incorrect.

Comment: @shoover To use, correct English only if you did not want. Or Yoda you were.

Comment: Another example of #2 with a preposition: "For unto us a child is given..."